# Why does integer promotion in pointer arithmetic behave differently in 64bit code than it does in 32bit code?

Tags: c++, pointer-arithmetic

When compiled for 64bit the following code crashes with an access violation when accessing `ptr[1-offset]`:

```
char* ptr = new char[4];
strcpy(ptr, "bar");
unsigned int offset = 2;
ptr+=offset;

char test0 = (ptr-offset)[2];
char test1 = ptr[2-offset];
char test2 = (ptr-offset)[1];
char test3 = ptr[1-offset];

delete (ptr-offset);
```

The code executes just fine when compiled for 32bit.

When I replace `ptr[1-offset]` by `ptr[(int)(1-offset)]` or alternatively when I change `unsigned int offset = 2;` into `int offset = 2;` the code executes just fine for 64bit, too.

Apparently on 64bit the result of `1-offset` gets promoted to an unsigned integer type, so that `ptr[1-offset]` does not resolve to `ptr[-1]`, but to `ptr[maxValueOfSomeUnsignedIntegerType]`.

However, why does this only happen for 64bit, while `1-offset` appears to get promoted to a signed integer type for 32bit?

This seems not to be implementation specific - I get the same results with VC++ and with G++.

Comment: *1-offset appears to get promoted to a signed integer type for 32bit* how do you prove that?

Comment: @Shafik: I guessed that from the observed behavior that it works without a cast on 32bit and gets fixed with an explicit cast to a signed int on 64bit

Comment: Note that this is UB either way. (Pretty sure at least.)

Comment: Notable: Arithmetic mixing signed and unsigned integer types can have surprising results.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the result of `1-offset` is always `UINT_MAX`, independent of your architecture. This alone does not explain the difference.

If you cast that to `int`, you get an implementation defined result, but that usually is `-1`. Same thing with `int offset`, you just get normal signed integer arithmetic that results in `-1`. So that works.

Now for why the segfault: Apparently, on the systems you tried, overflowing arithmetic on pointers wraps mod 2^32. As far as I know this is UB, but it seems to work on your systems. So you effectively end up with `ptr[1]`.

On the other hand, if the pointer is 64 bits wide, it can represent `ptr + 2^32 - 1` (at least in this case apparently), so no wrapping happens and the pointer points to some nonsense location about 4GB after what you allocated.

Answer (score 3):

`1` is of type `int`.
`offset` is of type `unsigned int`.

Integer promotion doesn't apply (that's only for types smaller than `int`).
Operator `-` then applies the usual arithmetic conversions. Because both inputs are of the same rank (`int`) and only differ in sign, the inputs get converted to type `unsigned int`.

So `1-offset` is always of type `unsigned int`, with value `UINT_MAX`. This applies to both 32-bit and 64-bit builds.

Indexing the pointer then causes an out-of-bounds access, so the code has undefined behavior on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms.

With 32-bit, the pointer calculation happens to wrap around so you get the same effect as `ptr[-1]` (assuming the optimizer doesn't exploit the UB), whereas on 64-bit the pointer calculation doesn't overflow, and you'll usually get a segfault.